# LVextend with live system, make the system see the extend

Tags: debian, lvm, debian-squeeze

Is there a way when extending an LVM of a VM, while this VM is still running, to make this virtual machine see the extension of his LVM volume without rebooting it?

Lets say I have 5 GB LVM volume with system X running on it (debian squeeze). X is on. I perform an LVextend on my hypervisor, X does not notice its disks have grown unless I reboot X.

Is there away to update something that I can extend X his harddrives while it is live AND not have to reboot it after the extend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your disk is seen as SCSI disk, issue a rescan: `echo "- - -" >/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan`, where `host0` is your SCSI adapter. Then check with `fdisk -l`if disk size got changed.

Then if you have created your LVM volumes straight on top of the disk without partitioning it, you should be ready to run `lvextend` at this point. If you have created your LVM volume on some partition, then you need to resize the partition first with `fdisk`or some other tool, and after that run `lvextend`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually go the other way around. I add "disks" (either file or lun backed) to the virtual machine and this is usually admitted without reboot by the guest machine. Then i use lvm in guest machine to add a new physical volume and add it to the required volume group.